# Workflow rule not firing up and email notification is not being sent when a user signs up for community created using ACM (anypoint community manager

Tags: community, mulesoft

I am troubleshooting an issue where we are not receiving email alerts when a new user signs up or registers for our community/API portal created using Mulesoft ACM (Anypoint Community Manager).

A "Workflow Rule" has been created with the below criteria:-

(Self Register User Request: Status NOT EQUAL TO Approved) AND (Self Register User Request: Status NOT EQUAL TO Rejected) AND (Self Register User Request: Community Id EQUALS ABCXYZ)

When the above criteria get satisfied, an email will be sent out to a list of recipients. An email alert is set up correctly.

Not sure where the issue is. There is a similar "workflow rule" present but with different criteria (Self Register User Request: Status NOT EQUAL TO Approved) AND (Self Register User Request: Status NOT EQUAL TO Rejected).

Since I am new to Salesforce, would be great if I can get some pointers on where to start troubleshooting this issue.

I can start by verifying whether the Community ID list in the above criteria is correct or not. Does anyone know where we can view the community ID of a particular community?